# Cygwin inherits environment variables from Windows sometimes

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, environment-variables

If I set the environment variable CVSROOT in Windows and give it a value like cvsserver:/home/cvs, if then

1) open Windows CMD shell and do "echo %CVSROOT%", I get "cvsserver:home/cvs"

2) open Cygwin bash shell and do "echo $CVSROOT", I get "cvsserver:home/cvs"

3) from Linux, ssh to the machine and do "echo $CVSROOT", I get nothing.

If I want the ssh session to have a value for CVSROOT, I need to insert it into the .bashrc.

Is there something that can be done so that the ssh session also inherits the environment variable from Windows?

edit:

4) from Linux, do

```
ssh machine "printenv CVSROOT"
```

with the environment variable set in .bashrc, I get nothing.  At an interactive prompt, I get the variable value, but this way gives nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice solution here: http://www.smithii.com/node/44

It looks for system variable in registry and sets variables in session opened via ssh.

Then, call the small piece of script from your ssh client (while connecting to your cygwin server), as this:
ssh $WINDOWSUSER@$WINDOWSBUILDSERVER "source /etc/profile ; echo  $CVSROOT "

Comment: /etc/profile should be sourced automatically. And today much more preferred to do not change it instead just create new file with provided script and place it into /etc/profile.d

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've figured it out...

For whatever reason, the bash shell is not inheriting the CVSROOT variable that is set on the system.  I need to put this line

```
export CVSROOT=cvsserver:/home/cvs
```

into both the .bashrc and the .bash_profile files.

The line is needed in the .bashrc file so that non-interactive logins will get the CVSROOT variable.  For example:

```
ssh machine "printenv CVSROOT"
```

needs this line in the .bashrc file so that CVSROOT exists.

The line is needed in the .bash_profile file so that interactive logins will get the CVSROOT variable.  For example:

```
ssh machine
printenv CVSROOT
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your SSH Service running on a windows box (I'm assuming you do) and it's via Cygwin.

The service seems to take a snapshot of the environment variables when it starts up and doesn't refresh them.

Restarting the service should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is Windows->Cygwin the other thing is ssh

have you tried forwarding your Windows variable to your linux explicitly:

```
ssh -t user@host "export CVSROOT=%CVSROOT%;/bin/bash --login"
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting your computer will solve this problem. Environment variable changes don’t just propagate to all your running programs.

Answer (score 0):

I hit upon the same problem. Got this working by setting the variable like this:

```
ssh machine "export MYVARIABLE=1 && printenv MYVARIABLE"
```